# How to generate a header of unknown size

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

Given

```
   import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
    import React from 'react';

    var products = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Item name 1",
        price: 100
    },{
        id: 2,
        name: "Item name 2",
        price: 100
    },];

    var DataTable = React.createClass({
       //This is not for-real dynamic.  If I can't wrap
       //N # of TableHeaderColumn's in a span then I can't solve the problem
      generateHeader(){
        return (
          <span>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true} dataAlign="center" dataSort={true}>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name" dataSort={true}>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price" dataFormat={this.priceFormatter}>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
          </span>
        );
      },
      // It's a data format example.
      priceFormatter(cell, row){
        return '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i> ' + cell;
      },

      render: function() {
        return (
          <BootstrapTable data={products} striped={true} hover={true}>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true} dataAlign="center" dataSort={true}>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name" dataSort={true}>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price" dataFormat={this.priceFormatter}>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
          </BootstrapTable>
        );
      }
    });

module.exports = DataTable;
```

I cannot call `generateHeader()` because react requires I wrap everything in a parent `<span>` in this case.  When I put TableHeaderColumn inside span the BootstrapTable breaks.

How can I generate a dynamic header?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the bootstrap table code, it doesn't look like you are allowed to wrap the columns in anything. I think you will need to rework your generateHeader() to loop and return the individual Columns. Something like

```
const cols = { //object or array
  {
    dataField: "id",
    value: "Product ID",
  },
  {}, ...
}
cols.map((col) => {
   return <TableHeaderColumn dataField={col.dataField}>{col.value}</TableHeaderColumn>;
})
```

This way you don't need to wrap the columns in the span. You create your object of your column data, then loop through those columns outputting the column header. This way, you can have dynamic data and if/else statements if needed.

I also want to clarify, React only requires that a single tag is returned, it doesn't need to be a `<span>`. I want to show you a method that renders columns, just to show you what you can do in your generateHeader().

```
  renderColumns(cols) {
    return (cols) ?
      cols.map((column) => {
        // You can set consts
        const style = Object.assign({}, styleObj.body2, styles.col, column.style);
        // You can use if statements
        if (typeof column == "string") {
          return <TableHeaderColumn style={style} key={column}>{column}</TableHeaderColumn>;
        } else {
          return <TableHeaderColumn style={style} key={column.columnHeader}>{column.columnHeader}</TableHeaderColumn>;
        }
      })
    : null; // If no columns return null
  }
```

Here is a more "complete" example

```
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import React from 'react';

var products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Item name 1",
    price: 100
},{
    id: 2,
    name: "Item name 2",
    price: 100
},];

var DataTable = React.createClass({
   //This is not for-real dynamic.  If I can't wrap
   //N # of TableHeaderColumn's in a span then I can't solve the problem
  generateHeader(){
    const cols = {
      {
        dataField: "id",
        value: "Product ID",
      }
    }
    cols.map((col) => {
       return <TableHeaderColumn dataField={col.dataField}>{col.value}</TableHeaderColumn>;
    })
  },
  // It's a data format example.
  priceFormatter(cell, row){
    return '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i> ' + cell;
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <BootstrapTable data={products} striped={true} hover={true}>
        {this.generateHeader()}
      </BootstrapTable>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = DataTable;
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work.  Can you provide a more complete example of the simple case (1st scenario)?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Can you post your modified code for the function? I want to see what you have (mainly how you are building the columns object). What errors do you get? I don't want to just write the function for you. What parts are you not understanding

Comment: Ok I updated the answer to include a complete example using the code you provided

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, not in the way I originally asked.  I ended up creating a `BootstrapTable` for each data model.